# scrapy spider not returning any results

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

This is my first attempt to create a spider, kindly spare me if I have not done it properly.
Here is the link to the website I am trying to extract data from. http://www.4icu.org/in/. I want the entire list of colleges that is being displayed on the page. But when I run the following spider I am returned with an empty json file. 
my items.py

```
    import scrapy
    class CollegesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
        link = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the spider
colleges.py

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
    from scrapy.http import Request

    class CollegesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
        link = scrapy.Field()

    class CollegesSpider(Spider):
        name = 'colleges'
        allowed_domains = ["4icu.org"]
        start_urls = ('http://www.4icu.org/in/',)

        def parse(self, response):
            return Request(
                url = "http://www.4icu.org/in/",
                callback = self.parse_fixtures
            )
        def parse_fixtures(self,response):
            sel = response.selector
            for div in sel.css("col span_2_of_2>div>tbody>tr"):
                item = Fixture()
                item['university.name'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="i"]/span  /a/text()').extract()
                yield item
```

Comment: Wow, for the first look you have some problems in your code. And because you do not get any exception when running the spider you can be assured you never reach the `parse_fixtures` method or at least the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment for the question there are some issues with your code.

First of all, you do not need two methods -- because in the `parse` method you call the same URL as you did in `start_urls`.

To get some information from the site try using the following code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for tr in response.xpath('//div[@class="section group"][5]/div[@class="col span_2_of_2"][1]/table//tr'):
        if tr.xpath(".//td[@class='i']"):
            name = tr.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            location = tr.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract()[0]
            print name, location
```

and adjust it to your needs to fill your item (or items).

As you can see, your browser displays an additional `tbody` in the `table` which is not present when you scrape with Scrapy. This means you often need to judge what you see in the browser.

Comment: Hi thanks for the guidance, its fetching the data. Below is the modified code and the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
    from scrapy.http import Request

    class CollegesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
        name = scrapy.Field()
        location = scrapy.Field()
    class CollegesSpider(Spider):
        name = 'colleges'
        allowed_domains = ["4icu.org"]
        start_urls = ('http://www.4icu.org/in/',)

        def parse(self, response):
            for tr in response.xpath('//div[@class="section group"] [5]/div[@class="col span_2_of_2"][1]/table//tr'):
                if tr.xpath(".//td[@class='i']"):
                    item = CollegesItem()
                    item['name'] = tr.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()').extract()[0]
                    item['location'] = tr.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract()[0]
                    yield item
```

after running the command 
spider

```
    >>scrapy crawl colleges -o mait.json
```

Following is the snippet of results:

```
    [[[[[[[{"name": "Indian Institute of Technology Bombay", "location": "Mumbai"},
    {"name": "Indian Institute of Technology Madras", "location": "Chennai"},
    {"name": "University of Delhi", "location": "Delhi"},
    {"name": "Indian Institute of Technology Kanpur", "location": "Kanpur"},
    {"name": "Anna University", "location": "Chennai"},
    {"name": "Indian Institute of Technology Delhi", "location": "New Delhi"},
    {"name": "Manipal University", "location": "Manipal ..."},
    {"name": "Indian Institute of Technology Kharagpur", "location": "Kharagpur"},
    {"name": "Indian Institute of Science", "location": "Bangalore"},
    {"name": "Panjab University", "location": "Chandigarh"},
    {"name": "National Institute of Technology, Tiruchirappalli", "location": "Tiruchirappalli"}, .........
```