# Why does this condition execute to false when it should execute to true?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code in my spider `basic.py` file:

```
if l.add_xpath('price', '//*[@id="price"]/text()',
            MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float),
            re = '[,.0-9]'):
    l.add_value('available', 1)
else:
    l.add_value('price', 0)
    l.add_value('available', 0)
```

The expected result is `available = 1` when there is a price found, but what I get is `0` and I don't understand why!

Any ideas?

Comment: it means the first if it's evaluating to false, therefore is using the else part or the if else statement.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, there's no way to know if your xpath expression is correct or not.

Comment: @wind85 But I used the same way in another place and it works as expected, only in this part the condition evaluates to false, which I can't figure out why!

Comment: @XO39 yes that's the problem with regular expressions you need to know them very well. Anyway please post the html code.

Comment: @Barmar the xpath is correct as it gets the price correctly! If it's not correct then I won't be able to get the price, right?

Comment: I don't see anything in the scrapy documentation that says that [`add_xpath`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader.add_xpath) returns a value. Why do you expect it to return something usable with `if`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there is nothing in the scrapy documentation that says that add_xpath returns a value, but I needed a way to check whether there is a value or not, I got the idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32052239). The odd thing is that it works `l.add_value('price', 0)` but not with `l.add_value('available', 0)`!

Comment: That uses `if tr.xpath(...)`, not `if tr.add_value(...)`. `xpath()` returns the element that matches the path or `None` if it can't find it.

Comment: @Barmar It's `add_xpath` not `add_value`, but I get you. I just want to know why does sets `price` to `0` ***ONLY*** when there is no `price` available in the page, but it sets `available` to `0` in both cases?  And how check if `add_xpath` found the desired element?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Scrapy, I only know what I read in the documentation. I can't think of any reason why the two would behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone ran into the same situation:

The answer is that `add_xpath` does not return anything, and in order to check whether there is an element found or not, `get_xpath` should be used instead ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37846006/587990)).