# How to check for unfound value with add_xpath in scrapy and set item value to a default value?

Tags: python, scrapy

Let's say I have this code:

```
def parse(self, response)
    l = ItemLoader(item=MyItem(), response=response
    l.add_xpath('title', '//*[@id="title"]/text()', MapCompose(str.strip, str.title)
    l.add_xpath('price', '//*[@id="price"]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float), re = '[,.0-9]')

    return l.load_item()
```

I want to check if no element found, in that case set a default value with `l.add_value`, for example (I tried doing this):

```
    if l.add_xpath('price', '//*[@id="price"]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float), re = '[,.0-9]'):
        l.add_value('available', 1)
    else:
        l.add_value('price', 0)
        l.add_value('available', 0)
```

But I got odd results ([see discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37842939/587990)).
Any ideas to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for `ItemLoader` is [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/loader/__init__.py).  The `add_xpath` method doesn't return anything (and so by default it returns `None`, so your `if` statement will always be `False`).

There does appear to be a `get_xpath` method that would appear to do what you want (check if the element exists).

Comment: Actually I got it working with `get_xpath` just after I posted my question, but I was too tired to come back and check for answers. Anyway, you got it right. Thanks :)